# PHP switch function not show true result

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this function for show type name :

```
function is_typename($type){

    switch ($type){
    case 1:
        echo "Bring an extra $500";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Bring an open mind";
        break;  
    case 3:
        echo "Bring 15 bottles of SPF 50 Sunscreen";
        break;  
    case 4:
        echo "Bring lots of money";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "Bring a swimsuit";
        break;  
    }

}
```

No for show link I have :

```
echo '<a href="'.SITE.''.$lang.'/'.is_typename($type).'/'.$id.'/'.$seotitle.'" rel="nofollow" title="'.$title.'" target="'.$target.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

in action i see :

```
Bring an extra $500<a href="http://localhost/cms/en//241/titeltest" rel="nofollow" title="titeltest" target="_blank">titeltest</a>
```

Problem: `$type` and typename show in outer `href` and `<a></a>`. how do fix this?

Comment: rather than echo out the data from the function , return it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of echo use return,

example

```
case 1:
        return "Bring an extra $500";
        break;
```